# Multiple continuous verbs

Tags: grammar

For three continuous verbs, which is right?

> 1a. Please can you help make the bed.
>
> 1b. Please can you help making the bed.
>
> 2a. An advisor can help expanding the width.
>
> 2b. An advisor can help expand the width.
>
> 3a. He can help come up with great ideas.
>
> 3b. He can help coming up with great ideas.

Comment: We also have [ell.se] that may interest you.

Comment: Please delete sentences 1a and 1b. They're inappropriate here as this 'please' isn't the verb, but the politeness marker. 1a may be paraphrased 'Kindly help (to) make the bed.